# How can I get multiple unique values from a JSON with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this JSON:

```
var dataM = '[{"category":"cat01","subcategory":"subcat01"},{"category":"cat01","subcategory":"subcat01"},{"category":"cat01","subcategory":"subcat03"}, {"category":"cat01","subcategory":"subcat03"},{"category":"cat01","subcategory":"subcat02"},{"category":"cat02","subcategory":"subcat04"},{"category":"cat02","subcategory":"subcat04"},{"category":"cat02","subcategory":"subcat02"},{"category":"cat01","subcategory":"subcat05"}]';
```

I want to get unique values and build an HTML unordered list structure , so I make this:

```js
var dataM = '[{"category":"cat01","subcategory":"subcat01"},{"category":"cat01","subcategory":"subcat01"},{"category":"cat01","subcategory":"subcat03"}, {"category":"cat01","subcategory":"subcat03"},{"category":"cat01","subcategory":"subcat02"},{"category":"cat02","subcategory":"subcat04"},{"category":"cat02","subcategory":"subcat04"},{"category":"cat02","subcategory":"subcat02"},{"category":"cat01","subcategory":"subcat05"}]';

var dataJSON = JSON.parse(dataM);
    var arrayM = []; var html='';

    for(i = 0; i< dataJSON.length; i++){    
        if(arrayM.indexOf(dataJSON[i].category) === -1){
            arrayM.push(dataJSON[i].category);        
        }        
    }

    html += '<ul>';

    for(i = 0; i< arrayM.length; i++){
        html += '<li>'+arrayM[i]+'</li>';
    }

    html += '</ul>';

$("#list").html(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="list"></div>
```

The problem is I only get the unique category values:

[image]

And I want to include the unique subcategory values of each category like this:

[image]

How can I fix it? I'd like to receive your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead off using an array, I'd recommend using an object so you can set each category on the key, push each subcategory into an array.

Then, if you only keep the [unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-a-javascript-array-remove-duplicates) subcats, you can use that array to show them:

```js
var dataM = '[{"category":"cat01","subcategory":"subcat01"},{"category":"cat01","subcategory":"subcat01"},{"category":"cat01","subcategory":"subcat03"}, {"category":"cat01","subcategory":"subcat03"},{"category":"cat01","subcategory":"subcat02"},{"category":"cat02","subcategory":"subcat04"},{"category":"cat02","subcategory":"subcat04"},{"category":"cat02","subcategory":"subcat02"},{"category":"cat01","subcategory":"subcat05"}]';

var dataJSON = JSON.parse(dataM);
var arrayM = {}; 
var html='';

for(i = 0; i < dataJSON.length; i++) {
    if (!arrayM[dataJSON[i].category]) {
        arrayM[dataJSON[i].category] = [];
    }
    arrayM[dataJSON[i].category].push(dataJSON[i].subcategory);
}

html += '<ul>';

for (let [category, subcategorys] of Object.entries(arrayM)) {
    html += '<li>'+category+'</li>';
    html += '<ul>';
    subcategorys = subcategorys.filter((v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v) === i);
    for (i = 0; i < subcategorys.length; i++) {
        html += '<li>'+subcategorys[i]+'</li>';
    }
    html += '</ul>';
}

html += '</ul>';

$("#list").html(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="list"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you can make use of `reducer` [Reducer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

By making use of reducer you can run filter and map together.

```js
var dataM = [{"category":"cat01","subcategory":"subcat01"},{"category":"cat01","subcategory":"subcat01"},{"category":"cat01","subcategory":"subcat03"}, {"category":"cat01","subcategory":"subcat03"},{"category":"cat01","subcategory":"subcat02"},{"category":"cat02","subcategory":"subcat04"},{"category":"cat02","subcategory":"subcat04"},{"category":"cat02","subcategory":"subcat02"},{"category":"cat01","subcategory":"subcat05"}];

    
    result = dataM.reduce(function (r, a) {
        r[a.category] = r[a.category] || [];
        r[a.category].push(a.subcategory);
        return r;
    }, Object.create(null));

html = '<ul>';

Object.keys(result).map(keys => {
html += "<li>" + keys + ":"
html += "<ul>"
result[keys].map( data => {
 html += "<li>"+data+"</li>" 
})
html+="</ul>"
});
html +="</ul>"
$("#list").html(html)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="list"></div>
```

Comment: Great use of reduce! OP is looking for 'unique values', so maybe you could implement that into your solution?

Comment: sure OStone, will update my answer with OP

Comment: Hi @Ostones, I have updated the code with expected OP

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I see subcats repeated, It must be unique